# MEAN Stack Express server going down

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, cloud, mean-stack

I am running a Node.JS + Angular JS application on a cloud server using the MEAN stack. The application is terminating every hour or sooner.

I have few thoughts and would like someone who can tell me which might a cause.
I am using SSH through root when I start the service using this command
NODE_ENV=production PORT=80 grunt serve:dist

Do I need forever to run this properly ? 
Should I use a server user (similar to apache) that can run the application?
If yes how do I do this ?

We do not have a deployment engineer in our team but it is annoying to not being able to keep the app running on the server after developing the application. Please help diagnose the problem.

Comment: NODE_ENV=production PORT=80 grunt serve:dist

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a deployment service — MS azure, AWS, heroku, etc. (which would probably be a lot easier) — then yes, you would have to use something like forever to restart your sever every time it crashes. It's really odd that your app terminates after an hour though, it'd be helpful if you could describe why that's happening.

Comment: I SSH as root and then go to /opt/myapp/ and run 
NODE_ENV=production PORT=80 grunt serve:dist
It goes down as my SSH session terminates ?
Is there a better way to do this like a script to run this command on start up ?